# How can I identify lines in files over a certain length

Tags: text-processing

I'd like to find lines in my code which exceed a certain length. My code is in multiple files. What's a good way to do this?

I'd like to know the files and line numbers; content would be preferred, but not necessary. The purpose of the exercise is to then figure out how to break the lines (probably manually).

Comment: How do you want the results? As the lines itself (their content, as in `grep`), or as line numbers, or as something else (perhaps you want to apply another action on them)? Probably the most convenietn way to do this depends on what will be done with these lines next.

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev Good point. Question updated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `grep`:

```
grep -En '.{12}' file
```

For lines at least 12 characters long.

With several files:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -En '.{12}' {} +
```

Some `grep` implementations like GNU `grep`, can do the file-finding themselves.

```
grep -rEn '.{12}' .
```

But beware of symlinks and other non-regular files.

Comment: I like this because it's simple, and I was hoping to do something like this (still haven't gotten around to it).

Answer (score 12):

**AWK solution**

```
awk '{       
if (length($0) > 5)
        print $0;'} yourfile
```

Or, more concisely:

```
awk 'length > 5' file
```

Comment: We can shorten your version `awk 'length > 5'`

Comment: Gnouc is a brace killer ;)

Comment: With  GNU `awk` the somewhat less elegant but concise `awk  '/^.{6,}/'`

Comment: Your first example has one mistake single quotes should be after end of close brace.

Comment: @RahulPatil Interesting. Both ways it is working :)

Comment: @1_CR, That's POSIX and can be shortened to `awk '/.{6}/'` (actually GNU awk until recently used to be the one where that wouldn't work unless you pass POSIXLY_CORRECT to its environment).

Answer (score 6):

**Bash solution**

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0

while read; do
    ((++count)) 
    len=${#REPLY}
    if ((len > 80)); then
        echo "Line $count is $len characters."
    fi
done
```

So, e.g., `./whatever.sh < input.file`.  This does not include the newline by subtracting 1 from `$len`; if that's not desirable, or your input uses CRLF endings, you should adjust accordingly.

Comment: why not `${#line}` to avoid the `expr` fork?

Comment: @1_CR Thanks!  But shh, you're gonna expose my general bash ineptitude (I'd just use perl here in real life)...forgot a string is an array of characters (which this also solves the `expr` = bytes issue).

Comment: ha ha, +1 for the pure `bash` solution. But please note that unless you stick in `IFS=` in front of `read`, leading spaces will be ignored.

Comment: @1_CR :) Decided to subtract 1 from $len as well to omit the newline.

Comment: Added in a few bash good practices. Also please note the the newline is not taken into `$line` so no need to subtract one.

Comment: @1_CR Whoop, and I actually checked on that (the count in line), erroneously (fed the script through itself and went `count=1`, "That's 6 characters..." >_< subconsciously counting 'ou' as one, I think).  Good to learn there is a pre-increment operator in bash, I can't stand +=1.  Just send an email off to the maintainer of the "Advanced Scripting Guide", btw, since **[sec 10.1](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)** claims `${#line}` and `expr length $line` "are [both] the equivalent of strlen() in C".

Comment: @1_CR Why would `(( $x > N ))` be considered a better practice than `[ $x -gt N ]`, BTW?

Comment: There are a few best practices related to bash arithmetic expressions [listed here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression). One key advantage of `(())` over `[[]]` is that it allows you to drop the `$` in front of shell variables

Comment: @1_CR actually if you don't give `read` a name to read into, it will read into `REPLY` and include all whitespace. No `IFS` setting needed.

Comment: @kojiro, and I used to think I knew all I needed to know about `read`. Thanks!

Comment: That's going to be extremely slow and handles the backslash characters specially. `while read` loops to process text are really bad practice.

Answer (score 5):

Since the one thing that was missing was a `sed` solution

```
sed -n '/^.\{6,\}/p' file
```

Answer (score 4):

With `perl` (for instance), assuming you are searching for lines longer than 80 characters:

To display the lines:

```
$ perl -nle 'print if length > 80' your_file
```

To display the lines number:

```
$ perl -nle 'print "$.\n" if length > 80' your_file
```

Or both:

```
$ perl -nle 'print "[$.]:  $_\n" if length > 80' your_file
```

Comment: You should add `-l` command line, `perl` will count line break in your lines.

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby :**

```
ruby -lne 'puts $_ if $_.size > 5' intputfile
```

**Python :**

```
python -c "import sys;[ sys.stdout.write(''.join(line)) for line in sys.stdin if len(line.strip()) > 5 ]" < inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another bash solution (bash 4):

```
minlen=5 # minimum length of a line
mapfile -tO1 < inputfile # Map the file to the array MAPFILE (by default)
                         # Start the array at index 1
for i in "${!MAPFILE[@]}"; do
  (( ${#MAPFILE[i]} > minlen )) || unset MAPFILE[i] # Remove shorter elements
done
```

The resulting array is sparse, so the array indices are maintained. Since we started at 1, the indices are the line numbers of the lines we kept. We can output just those line numbers:

```
printf 'Long lines found at: '
printf '%d, ' "${!MAPFILE[@]}"
echo
```

Or we can output the lines themselves:

```
printf '%s\n' "${MAPFILE[@]}"
```